# VS Code: "Cannot find module" from root path

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I cannot seem to solve a module import issue with Visual Studio Code:

[image: Cannot find module]

I've a setup a [sample repo to illustrate](https://github.com/brianmhunt/bug-reports/tree/vscode-ts-module-import) this problem, with a directory structure like this:

```
➜ tree -I node_modules
.
├── README.md
├── packages
│   ├── jsx
│   │   └── jsx.jsx
│   ├── tjs
│   │   └── tjs.js
│   ├── tscript
│   │   └── tscript.js
│   └── tsx
│       └── tsx.tsx
├── src
│   ├── entry.ts
│   └── localjs.js
└── tsconfig.json
```

I'd like to have this setup work with [babel-typescript](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript), but my investigation indicates that the problem seems to be intrinsic to VSCode, so I've left it out of the sample.

I've tried all the permutations of the `paths` for `tsconfig.json` that I've seen i.e.

```
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "*",
        "packages/*",
        "packages/*/index.tsx",
        "packages/*/index.jsx",
        "packages/*/index.js"
      ],
      "$1": [
        "packages/$1/$1"
      ],
      "~/*": [
        "packages/*"
      ],
      "~/$1": [
        "packages/$1/$1"
      ],
      "*/$1": [
        "*/$1/$1",
        "packages/$1/$1",
        "*/packages/$1/$1"
      ]
    }
```

The [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#tracing-module-resolution) doesn't offer much insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already got an [answer from Wex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55072082/1906307) suggesting that you rename your files to have the basename `index` plus the appropriate extension and use the mapping `"*"*: ["*", "packages/*"]`. You mentioned in a comment that you'd rather avoid renaming the files. Besides avoiding renames, I'm not a fan of having a lot of files be named `index.<some_extension>`. When working, my eyes are naturally drawn to the basename of the files I'm working on or getting reports about. Having to distinguish files that have near-identical basenames by directory is possible but requires more cognitive work on my part to look away from the basename and at the path, or more work at the keyboard for completion. (It takes longer to type. There's only so much help the IDE can provide.) It is enough to be annoying.

First, let's deal with the dead ends. I see no evidence that `~` and `$1` are treated specially in `paths`. I went to check `tsc`'s code and see nothing there that handles such patterns. It could be that I missed it, but I think they are just *not special*. Also, *ignoring extensions for the moment*, your desired mapping is something `packages/<package_name>/<package_name>.ext` The package name appears twice. So it would be tempting to set a mapping like `"*": ["packages/*/*.ext"]` but that's explicitly not allowed by TypesScript: `tsc` will give you an error about the two asterisks appearing in the desired mapping. So that's not an option either.

#### Use `package.json`

You could dodge the renaming issue by adding a `package.json` to each package with a `"main"` field that points to the file you want to be considered the entry point of your package. For instance, `packages/jsx/package.json` could contain this:

```
{
  "main": "jsx.jsx"
}
```

By providing similar files for all other packages, you can reduce the relevant configuration to:

```
"baseUrl": "",
"paths": {
  "*": ["packages/*", "*"]
},
```

Or you can use `"baseUrl"` to point to your packages and omit `"paths"` entirely:

```
"baseUrl": "packages/",
```

Make sure that you lint the `package.json` files because `tsc` will simply *ignore them silently* if there's any syntactic mistake in these files.

#### Add `index` Files that Reexport your Entry Module

Another method would be to use index files that simply reexport all of the file you'd otherwise want to be the entry point of your package. The files you currently have would remain there but would be referenced by appropriately designed `index` files. For instance, `packages/tsx/index.ts` could be:

```
export { default } from "./tsx";
```

If all your packages just provide a default export, they could all follow the pattern above. Otherwise, if a package exports multiple symbols and just want to reexport everything, you can do:

```
export * from "./myModule";
```

If you do this for all your packages, you don't need to rename anything but you'd have additional `index` files to satisfy the `"*": ["*", "packages/*"]` mapping.

In a comment, you mentioned using a tool like Barrelsby to generate `index` files. I'd be concerned about the impact on development. I can see generating an index file acting as a facade as part of publishing your project. So people consuming the published project deal with a file generated by Barrelsby or some other tool. However, your `index` files appear to me to be *internal* to your project. So in order to get proper IDE support *while developing* the index files will have to already exist before contributors start contributing. So contributors would have to run something that generates the index files before they start contributing. You would also have generated files that live side by side with files that are authored directly by developers. I try to avoid this in my projects.

If it were my project and I decided to add `index` files to satisfy the `tsconfig.json` mapping, I'd aim to structure my project so that the `index` files boil down to one of the two cases above, and skip using a code generator. (Actually, I'd aim for the 2nd of the two cases above, because I prefer to avoid default exports. See [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/defaultIsBad.html) for a discussion of the issues with default exports.)

#### Individually Map The Packages

If the other solutions are problematic for your specific project, you can provide one mapping per package:

```
"paths": {
  "jsx": ["packages/jsx/jsx.jsx"],
  "tjs": ["packages/tjs/tjs.js"],
  "tscript": ["packages/tscript/tscript.js"],
  "tsx": ["packages/tsx/tsx.tsx"],
},
```

This means adding a mapping each time you add a new package. Whether or not this is viable depends on your specific project. You could also use a `baseUrl` set to `"packages/"` and remove `packages/` from all the paths above:

```
"baseUrl": "packages/",
"paths": {
  "jsx": ["jsx/jsx.jsx"],
  "tjs": ["tjs/tjs.js"],
  "tscript": ["tscript/tscript.js"],
  "tsx": ["tsx/tsx.tsx"],
},
```

This makes the whole thing less verbose though you still have to provide one mapping per package.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Louis.  Editing the tsconfig for each module would be madness (we add/remove/edit 2-3 a week, we'd be clobbering git commits routinely, and our tsconfig would be thousands of lines long).  So that's not very practical.  However I stumbled across a plugin — [module-plugin-d-ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-plugin-d-ts.html)?  Do you think this or perhaps another TS plugin might assist in solving this problem?

Comment: Sounds like you've got a special case.  I don't see `module-plugin.d.ts` as pertaining to your problem. It illustrates how you can *augment* a module. For instance, when you load a jQuery plugin, jQuery *itself* gains new methods. e.g If you load Bootstrap, then jQuery gets `$().modal`, `$().dropdown`, ... which are not on the stock jQuery. It is puzzling at first to figure how to declare the interface for such a plugin. Search for "module plugin" on [this page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/library-structures.html) for the context to `module-plugin.d.ts`.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me get my bearings.  It looks (to my untrained eye) as though  [Barrelsby](https://github.com/bencoveney/barrelsby) might be a viable option to solve the crux of the issue by auto-generating the index.ts files.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt Comments are too small to respond to your Barrelsby idea, so I've added a new section to my answer.

Comment: Hi Louis, thanks for the additional section, which I'm digesting.  For context, I was thinking of Barrelsby as a stop-gap for our private project until a.) we convert on an as-needed basis, or b.) Typescript gets proper compiler plugins that allow directory-named-index-files.

Comment: I think this is essentially the best answer right now, though for future reference I think it could be improved by adding a link to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html and note that `tsc` also looks for `main` and /or `types` property in `package.json` (and also an `@types` path) and will use that to resolve the package.

Comment: I actually tried putting `package.json` into the `packages/*/` subdirectories... but it did not work. I still have that trial on disk, so I went back to it just now and looked again. *Sigh* I had an errant trailing comma in the JSON, which caused `tsc` to *silently* pretend that the `package.json` is absent. Once I removed the comma, it worked. If I had not made that mistake, I would have mentioned it in the first place. I'm going to edit my answer to include that possibility.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, thanks Louis. I think that'll help the next person to happen across this.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the issue with your [current `tsconfig.json`](https://github.com/brianmhunt/bug-reports/blob/31208689977acef41196aba9dfb6d17db5e4a504/tsconfig.json) is that you are using `include: []`, so no code will actually be matched by your config!

I couldn't find any examples of using the `$1` pattern the way you have it in your sample config, nor do I think what you are trying to do is possible based on some research (see also: [#5039](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039)). Are you able to rename `{package}/{package}.jsx` to `{package}/index.jsx`? Then your paths config could trivially be changed to:

```
    "paths": {
      "*": ["*", "packages/*"]
    },
```

Comment: Thanks @wex.  I copied the `$1` code from a comment on [#24116](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24116#issuecomment-389378865), though that's it.    That's a great link to #5039, I'll dig into it more.  Thanks for the suggestion to rename packages to `{package}/index.js`.  It'd involve a huge number lot of file changes, so we'd prefer to avoid it, but it's good to know it's a backstop.